# How can I use js.erb in redmine plugin-development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, redmine

Due to the fact that the asset pipeline es deactivated, how can I use js.erb - files in plugin-development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files (i.e. files in `app/views/**/*.js.erb`) are used as the view for an actual web request. There, the assets pipeline would never kick in at all.

Instead, you can just return the response as you normally would for html. Just make sure to correctly set the format on your `render` call in your controller, e.g.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

or (in case the requested format is not set as js), you can use an explicit render call:

```
render format: :js
```